# Installing ROS on Debian

Tags: ros, gumstix, debian, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have a problem getting ROS up and running on my gumstix board.My configuration is:

Operating Platform : Gumstix
Operating System ( on the board ): Debian
ROS version : electric

I followed a tutorial on ROS.org (ttp://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Debian) to install ROS. After i install all the components i try to start the roscore with the command : " roscore "
And i get the fallowing output:

```
File "/root/ros/ros/bin/roscore", line 34, in <module>
  from ros import roslaunch
File "/root/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/ros/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
  return __import__(name)
File "/root/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 53, in>
  from roslaunch.scriptapi import ROSLaunch
File "/root/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/scriptapi.py", line 42, i>
  import roslaunch.parent
File "/root/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/parent.py", line 55, in <>
  import roslaunch.server
File "/root/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/server.py", line 70, in <>
  from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Log
ImportError: No module named rosgraph_msgs.msg
```

Then i ran the command " roswtf " and it's output is :

ERROR: The ROS communication libraries have not been built. To fix:
rosmake ros_comm

Then i run " rosmake ros_comm " and i get :

```
Could not detect OS. platform detection will not work
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ros_comm']                                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/root/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121208-183849
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ros_comm'] to:
['cpp_common', 'rostime', 'xmlrpcpp', 'roswtf', 'message_filters', 'rospy',     'rosli]
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages ros_comm.  This may take a fe.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/ros/ros/bin/rosmake", line 69, in <module>
if rma.main():
  File "/root/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 872, in main
    self.printer.print_all("rosdep check failed to find system dependencies: %s"% )
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/ros/ros/bin/rosmake", line 69, in <module>
    if rma.main():
  File "/root/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 872, in main
    self.printer.print_all("rosdep check failed to find system dependencies: %s"%)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

When i run roswtf again i get the same error as before and roscore still does not initialize.

Please help me with this problem because i cannot figure out what is missing or not working properly. I thank you in advance for your answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49977/installing-ros-on-debian/) by [crys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3748/crys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-12-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are missing a system dependency, but due to a small bug we cannot tell which.
fix the bug by editing "/root/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 872

```
self.printer.print_all("rosdep check failed to find system dependencies: %s" % self.rosdep_check_result)
```

and run again. This line is already fixed in the electric source,
https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros/branches/ros-1.6/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py
but apparently was not released with version 1.6.9 of the ros stack.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1